# Prove that $\|v\|$ is the supremum of this set.

Tags: inner-products, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then I need to prove

$\|v\| = \sup\{\langle v,u\rangle , u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ \|u\| =  1\}$

I know that in the set on $S  = \{\langle v,u\rangle \|u\| =1$} if $v \ne  0$  $u  =  \dfrac{v}{\|v\|}$

gives $\langle v, u\rangle = \|v\|$ but how to show this is the least upper bound for this set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Cauchy Schwarz inequality we get $$\langle v, u\rangle\leq \|v\|\cdot 1 =\|v\|.$$
Therefore $$\sup\{\langle v, u\rangle : \|u\|=1\}\leq \|v\|$$
but for $u=\frac{v}{\|v\|}$ we get $$\langle v, u\rangle=\frac{\|v\|^2}{\|v\|}= \|v\|$$
so $$\sup\{\langle v, u\rangle : \|u\|=1\}= \|v\|.$$